# git "remote: No git jobs using repository: repo.git and branches"

Tags: git

In the beginning there was a folder with files from which I've made `repo1.git`, then I decided to create `repo2.git` from the same set of files. I did it by replicating `repo1` in some way I don't remember exactly now.

Currently I'm working with `repo2`, everything works fine but I've noted a strange message after pushing `repo2`. It says:

```
...
remote: No git jobs using repository: repo1 and branches:
remote: No Git consumers using SCM API plugin for repo1
To repo2
849871f..4f0dd1f master -> master
```

What the meaning of these references to `repo1`? Is it possible to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to answer, since this relies on the setup you have on the remote server-side (in other words; it's not a standard function of Git).

Chances are that the message is being displayed through some remote validation plug-in, and that is being picked up from some other means (such as a configuration file that's been added to the repository that's specific to your set-up). It's also possible that the message has nothing to do with what you've called your local repository, but that the remote server happens to have used `repo1` when you set it up and now does the same thing.